# How to get a specific commit from Git as-is

Tags: git

Somehow, someone on our team messed up our repo and we have some problems with building our website.  I am trying to go back to earlier commits, but when I tried to do a

`git fetch origin [HASH_OF_COMMIT]`

then

`git checkout FETCH_HEAD`

and then build my project, I am getting tons of build errors.  The thing is that I know this commit is stable, so I think Git is just merging this commit with what I already have in some way which is causing problems.  How can I go back to the EXACT code base that existed at time of this commit?

Answer (score 1):

Try a git reset --hard HASH_OF_COMMIT.